# Create ID variable from continued index of other table

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables in SQL:

- Prod
- Staging

New table entries are added to the SQL table via Pandas so I end up with the following row counts:

- Prod 520000
- Staging 530000

The Prod db has primary ID key which is generated from the pd index, counting all the way up to 520000.

In my script I remove all common entries from both tables so the new ones can be appended to the Prod table. Is there a way I can take the highest ID/ index value for the new entries and count from there?

Prod_increment has 10000 rows but the ID variable should start counting from the max ID of the Prod table, so the first row should have ID 520001.

I tried using the index of the Prod table but I get an error that the two index sizes are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Prod_increment.index += (Prod.index[-1]+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked in my solution! I did include it in a try/ except clause in case the prod table is empty for some reason/ initial fill.